# Arrow head at the last path segment of Bezier curve

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, flow

I am making a flow map. For most flows, I used the curved arrow symbology associated with lines.

For my Mediterranean flow, I have to draw a path that ends with an arrow.
I use the Bezier plugin to get curves.

Question: How to keep this path and keep only one arrow?

Issue: When I uncheck in the arrow symbology repeat the arrow for each segment, I only get a *"big"* curved arrow and I allow my path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try geometry generator with:

```
make_line(point_n( $geometry, -2), end_point($geometry))
```

The second last point and last/end point is used to create a line:

[image]

Comment: I am begining with geomtry generator I tried to reproduce your example without success. What is the sequence ? I begin with a line and after ?

Comment: Start with default line symbol, simple line. Click the plus sign to duplicate it. Click the line, for type of symbol layer select geometry generator. Then select "line" for geometry type. What do you mean by "without success"? If you have a smooth curve with lots of vertices you might need to change -2 to maybe -20 or something

Comment: Thanks for helping. it works But I need to improve the symbologie. I am going to post a new question