# Change size, color for nested styles consisting of different symbol layers created with geometry generator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, geometry-generator

In QGIS 3.16, I have a nested linestyle that consists of different symbol layers. I am able to change the width, color and other settings manually for each symbol layer. However, I want to be able to change the setting for the whole composed symbol at once, as it is possible with some pre-defined styles.

In the example below (topo railway) is a pre-defined style that is shipped with QGIS and is for illustration purpose to show how the solution should work. The topo railway style consists of a marker line (no. 2) and a simple line (no. 3). If I change the size of the composed linestyle (no 1), the size of no. 2 and 3 changes proportionally.

How to achieve that if you start to compose an own style with different symbol layers?

Updated question: I have symbol layers created with geometry generator. See here for an example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380267/88814
Especially these symbol layers are the problem - with other kind of symbol layers, setting the global size works.

Update 2: As a workaround, I can use a variable (global or per project) that can be used to define the size, width etc. of the different symbol layers. However, this is not very useful if the style thus created should be exported (using QGIS style manager) and used on another computer. One will have to define the variable separately on each system (or project).

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused.  In your first paragraph, you indicate that you want the symbols to all change "...at once."  Then in the second paragraph, you say that if you change no. 1, "...no. 2 and 3 changes proportionally."  But isn't that what you wanted in your first paragraph?  Looks to me as if it is doing what you want.  What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry to be confusing, I edited the question. You're right, the example on the screenshot does exactly what I want - this was for illustration purpose of how the solution should work. However, I have an own nested style and in this case, I'm not able to achieve this result. So I was wondering how in the topo railway example this was done - I inspected it in detail but could not find any clue.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helps clarify.  I see what you mean - very interesting.  Sorry that I don't have a solution, but I'll be following this thread!

Comment: Version 3.14 - changing "global" width affects all compound layers (including size of the marker) for my custom style. I'm not convinced yet to upgrade to 3.16 just to see if it is version issue...

Comment: @Szym, you're right, changing "global" width does affect all compound layers - expect those created with geometry generator. So I will update the question accordingly

Comment: @babel, yes, so it looks like only geometry generator is the issue (naturally also in 3.14).