# Visualizing a polyline with decreasing width towards one end (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, style, width

I am acquiring data related to the hydrography of a territory. I would like to use a symbology that allows me to have a line whose thickness decreases as it reaches its end (like the example in the image).

[image: example]

I could divide each line into many segments and give each one its own thickness, but I'm looking for a much faster and more effective method. The geometry generator could probably be a solution .

Currently, I have vectorized each waterway with a single line.

[image: example 2]

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: see this closely related [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379543/path-ending-with-an-arrow-need-to-improve-symbology/379565#379565)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try geometry generator:

```
 tapered_buffer( $geometry, 10, 50)
```

[image]